# Using this::some_method_reference as a listener creates a new lambda reference. Why?

Tags: java

I am trying to understand why using this::someMethod when registering as a listener creates multiple lambda instances each time I register.

For example.  The following code is broken and I am trying to understand the rationale for why the java designers implemented it this way.

```
class A {
  private JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem();

  public void addListener() {
    menuItem.addActionListener(this::clickHandler);
    menuItem.removeActionListener(this::clickHandler);
  }

  private void clickHandler(final ActionEvent e) {
     /** do stuff here **/
  }
}
```

If you do the above, the listener is never removed from the JMenuItem.  I would have expected that the second lambda would be the same as the first?

Keen to understand why this was done this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At runtime, Lambdas are objects, as stated in [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.4):

> At run time, evaluation of a lambda expression is similar to evaluation of a class instance creation expression, insofar as normal completion produces a reference to an object. Evaluation of a lambda expression is distinct from execution of the lambda body.
>
> Either a new instance of a class (...) is allocated and initialized, or an existing instance of a class (...) is referenced.

So, this explains that:

```
menuItem.addActionListener(this::clickHandler);
menuItem.removeActionListener(this::clickHandler);
```

Is similar (but not really the same) to have this:

```
menuItem.addActionsListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        this.clickHandler(e);
    }
});
menuItem.removeActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        this.clickHandler(e);
    }
});
```

This may explain why your code doesn't behave as expected.

Note that the reuse of a lambda as objects depends of JVM implementation.